# ec2 Apache Server http-500 troubleshooting

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, yum, 500-error

My website was being funky so I rebooted my server.  I also ran sudo yum update and updated everything.  Now my website wont load (www.kisnardonline.com) and I get http-500 errors.  I am not 100% sure if it was related to the update or not.  I have googled a bunch, but have no ideas what else to look at.

It looks like the update did not overwrite my config files so I am not sure what could have broken?

I am able to SSH to my server.  I am able to connect to my MySQL db.  I am able to run my java game server and connect with my game client from my local pc.  Top output looks fine to me (plenty of memory and cpu).  Anything else I can check?

**yum history info 77**

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Transaction ID : 77
Begin time     : Thu Nov  2 23:49:20 2017
Begin rpmdb    : 482:891f2e1355453f459cb67e212feb05d2fcd0d421
End time       :            23:50:29 2017 (69 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 492:cfa44d8f63026943da406a0b769ab02395772f96
User           : EC2 Default User <ec2-user>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : update
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 @amzn-main
    Updated       yum-3.4.3-150.68.amzn1.noarch @amzn-main
Packages Altered:
    Updated     authconfig-6.2.8-10.28.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Update                 6.2.8-30.31.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Updated     aws-amitools-ec2-1.5.12-0.1.amzn1.noarch                      @amzn-main
    Update                       1.5.13-0.2.amzn1.noarch                      @amzn-main
    Updated     aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4-15.9.amzn1.noarch                       @amzn-updates
    Update                        1.4-24.16.amzn1.noarch                      @amzn-updates
    Updated     aws-cli-1.11.83-1.46.amzn1.noarch                             @amzn-updates
    Update              1.11.132-1.47.amzn1.noarch                            @amzn-main
    Updated     bash-4.2.46-20.36.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-main
    Update           4.2.46-28.37.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-main
    Updated     bind-libs-32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.54.amzn1.x86_64                   @amzn-updates
    Update                32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.56.amzn1.x86_64                   @amzn-main
    Updated     bind-utils-32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.54.amzn1.x86_64                  @amzn-updates
    Update                 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.56.amzn1.x86_64                  @amzn-main
    Updated     binutils-2.23.52.0.1-55.65.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-updates
    Update               2.25.1-31.base.66.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     curl-7.51.0-4.73.amzn1.x86_64                                 @amzn-main
    Update           7.53.1-10.77.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-updates
    Updated     datadog-agent-1:5.13.2-1.x86_64                               @datadog
    Update                    1:5.18.1-1.x86_64                               @datadog
    Updated     ec2-net-utils-0.5-1.32.amzn1.noarch                           @amzn-updates
    Update                    0.5-1.33.amzn1.noarch                           @amzn-main
    Updated     ec2-utils-0.5-1.32.amzn1.noarch                               @amzn-updates
    Update                0.5-1.33.amzn1.noarch                               @amzn-main
    Updated     file-5.22-4.31.amzn1.x86_64                                   @amzn-updates
    Update           5.30-11.34.amzn1.x86_64                                  @amzn-main
    Updated     file-libs-5.22-4.31.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-updates
    Update                5.30-11.34.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-main
    Updated     glibc-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-updates
    Update            2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-main
    Updated     glibc-common-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-updates
    Update                   2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Updated     glibc-devel-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-updates
    Update                  2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     glibc-headers-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-updates
    Update                    2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     grep-2.20-2.17.amzn1.x86_64                                   @amzn-main
    Update           2.20-3.18.amzn1.x86_64                                   @amzn-main
    Updated     grubby-7.0.15-5.7.amzn1.x86_64                                ?
    Update             7.0.15-7.8.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-main
    Updated     gzip-1.5-8.18.amzn1.x86_64                                    @amzn-main
    Update           1.5-9.19.amzn1.x86_64                                    @amzn-main
    Updated     httpd24-2.4.25-1.68.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-updates
    Update              2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-main
    Updated     httpd24-tools-2.4.25-1.68.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-updates
    Update                    2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Updated     initscripts-9.03.49-1.35.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-updates
    Update                  9.03.58-1.39.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     java-1.8.0-openjdk-1:1.8.0.131-2.b11.30.amzn1.x86_64          @amzn-updates
    Update                         1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64          @amzn-updates
    Updated     java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.131-2.b11.30.amzn1.x86_64 @amzn-updates
    Update                                  1:1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64 @amzn-updates
    Erase       kernel-4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-updates
    Install     kernel-4.9.58-18.51.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-updates
    Updated     kernel-headers-4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64                      @amzn-updates
    Update                     4.9.58-18.51.amzn1.x86_64                      @amzn-updates
    Updated     krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.41.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-updates
    Update                1.15.1-8.43.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-updates
    Updated     krb5-workstation-1.14.1-27.41.amzn1.x86_64                    @amzn-updates
    Update                       1.15.1-8.43.amzn1.x86_64                     @amzn-updates
    Updated     libcurl-7.51.0-4.73.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-main
    Update              7.53.1-10.77.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-updates
    Updated     libgcc48-4.8.3-9.111.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-main
    Update               4.8.5-11.135.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Updated     libkadm5-1.14.1-27.41.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-updates
    Update               1.15.1-8.43.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-updates
    Dep-Install libnghttp2-1.21.1-1.4.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Updated     libstdc++48-4.8.3-9.111.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-main
    Update                  4.8.5-11.135.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-20.4.8.3.31.amzn1.x86_64                   @amzn-main
    Update                   2.4.2-20.4.8.5.32.amzn1.x86_64                   @amzn-main
    Updated     mod24_ssl-1:2.4.25-1.68.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-updates
    Update                1:2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql-config-5.5.56-1.17.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-updates
    Update                   5.5.57-1.18.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql56-5.6.36-1.25.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-updates
    Update              5.6.37-1.26.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql56-common-5.6.36-1.25.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-updates
    Update                     5.6.37-1.26.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql56-errmsg-5.6.36-1.25.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-updates
    Update                     5.6.37-1.26.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql56-libs-5.6.36-1.25.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-updates
    Update                   5.6.37-1.26.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     mysql56-server-5.6.36-1.25.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-updates
    Update                     5.6.37-1.26.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     nss-3.28.4-1.0.78.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-updates
    Update          3.28.4-12.80.amzn1.x86_64                                 @amzn-updates
    Dep-Install nss-pem-1.0.3-4.3.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-updates
    Updated     nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-14.4.39.amzn1.x86_64                     @amzn-updates
    Update                  3.28.3-8.41.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-updates
    Updated     nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.4.39.amzn1.x86_64              @amzn-updates
    Update                         3.28.3-8.41.amzn1.x86_64                   @amzn-updates
    Updated     nss-sysinit-3.28.4-1.0.78.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-updates
    Update                  3.28.4-12.80.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-updates
    Updated     nss-tools-3.28.4-1.0.78.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-updates
    Update                3.28.4-12.80.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-updates
    Updated     nss-util-3.28.4-1.0.52.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-updates
    Update               3.28.4-3.53.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-updates
    Updated     openssh-6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Update              7.4p1-11.68.amzn1.x86_64                              @amzn-main
    Updated     openssh-clients-6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1.x86_64                    @amzn-main
    Update                      7.4p1-11.68.amzn1.x86_64                      @amzn-main
    Updated     openssh-server-6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1.x86_64                     @amzn-main
    Update                     7.4p1-11.68.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     openssl-1:1.0.1k-15.99.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Update              1:1.0.2k-7.103.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Install     php56-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-main
    Dep-Install php56-cli-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Dep-Install php56-common-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Install     php56-gd-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Dep-Install php56-jsonc-1.3.10-1.20.amzn1.x86_64                          @amzn-updates
    Install     php56-pdo-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Dep-Install php56-process-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Install     php56-xml-5.6.31-1.134.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-main
    Update            7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                                @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-cli-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Update                7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-common-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Update                   7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                         @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-gd-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-main
    Update               7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                             @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-json-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Update                 7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                           @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-mbstring-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Update                     7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                       @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-mysqlnd-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Update                    7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-opcache-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Update                    7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-pdo-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Update                7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-process-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Update                    7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                        @amzn-main
    Updated     php70-xml-7.0.16-1.21.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Update                7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64                            @amzn-main
    Updated     python26-botocore-1.5.46-1.63.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-updates
    Update                        1.5.95-1.65.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-main
    Updated     python26-setuptools-12.2-1.32.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-main
    Update                          36.2.7-1.33.amzn1.noarch                  @amzn-main
    Updated     python27-botocore-1.5.46-1.63.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-updates
    Update                        1.5.95-1.65.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-main
    Updated     python27-setuptools-12.2-1.32.amzn1.noarch                    @amzn-main
    Update                          36.2.7-1.33.amzn1.noarch                  @amzn-main
    Updated     sqlite-3.7.17-6.13.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-updates
    Update             3.7.17-8.14.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-main
    Updated     sudo-1.8.6p3-25.23.amzn1.x86_64                               ?
    Update           1.8.6p3-29.27.amzn1.x86_64                               @amzn-main
    Updated     system-release-2017.03-0.0.noarch                             @amzn-main
    Update                     2017.09-0.0.noarch                             @amzn-main
    Updated     wget-1.18-1.18.amzn1.x86_64                                   @amzn-updates
    Update           1.18-3.28.amzn1.x86_64                                   @amzn-updates
    Updated     yum-3.4.3-150.68.amzn1.noarch                                 @amzn-main
    Update          3.4.3-150.70.amzn1.noarch                                 @amzn-main
    Updated     yum-python26-3.4.3-150.68.amzn1.noarch                        @amzn-main
    Update                   3.4.3-150.70.amzn1.noarch                        @amzn-main
Scriptlet output:
   1 warning: /etc/nsswitch.conf created as /etc/nsswitch.conf.rpmnew
   2 warning: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security created as /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security.rpmnew
   3 warning: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/nss.cfg created as /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.35.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/nss.cfg.rpmnew
   4 warning: /etc/issue.net created as /etc/issue.net.rpmnew
   5 warning: /etc/sysctl.conf created as /etc/sysctl.conf.rpmnew
   6 warning: /etc/ssh/sshd_config created as /etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew
   7 warning: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf created as /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.rpmnew
   8 Stopping Datadog Agent (using killproc on supervisord): [  OK  ]
   9 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.order: remove failed: No such file or directory
  10 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.networking: remove failed: No such file or directory
  11 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.modesetting: remove failed: No such file or directory
  12 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.drm: remove failed: No such file or directory
  13 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.builtin: remove failed: No such file or directory
  14 warning: file /lib/modules/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64/modules.block: remove failed: No such file or directory
  15 warning: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-2.b11.30.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security saved as /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-2.b11.30.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security.rpmsave
  16 (Re)starting datadog-agent now...
  17 Stopping Datadog Agent (using killproc on supervisord): [FAILED]
  18 Starting Datadog Agent (using supervisord):[  OK  ]
history info
```

**/etc/httpd/logs/error_log**

```
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:47.152945 2017] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 2772:tid 139963340687424] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:47.971191 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 3238:tid 139837959862336] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:47.992314 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3239:tid 139837959862336] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:48.008075 2017] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 3239:tid 139837959862336] AH00292: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:48.008099 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3239:tid 139837959862336] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[Fri Nov 03 00:28:52.012474 2017] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 3239:tid 139837959862336] AH00287: server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxRequestWorkers, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

**ps -ef**

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root        10     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [lru-add-drain]
root        11     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        12     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        13     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        14     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        15     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        16     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        17     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        18     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        19     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u30:1]
root        23     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u30:2]
root        25     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root        26     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [xenbus]
root        27     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
root       149     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root       150     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [oom_reaper]
root       151     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root       153     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kcompactd0]
root       154     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root       155     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
root       156     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root       157     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root       158     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       160     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root       510     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root       515     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root       641     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root       642     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [vmstat]
root       739     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root       791     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root      1472     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root      1485     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root      1486     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root      1489     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root      1490     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root      1544     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root      1545     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root      1573     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root      1591     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1723  1591  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1724  1591  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1897     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root      1906     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root      1922     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 lvmetad
root      1931     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 lvmpolld
root      1987     2  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root      2138     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      2194     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 auditd
root      2221     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      2235     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid --hintpolicy=subset
dbus      2251     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      2286     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root      2386     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
ntp       2408     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
root      2487     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedi
mysql     2701  2487  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql56/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld
root      2748     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     2757     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root      2784     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 crond
root      2798     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd
dd-agent  2862     1  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/bin/supervisord -c /etc/dd-agent/supervisor.conf
dd-agent  2867  2862  0 00:26 ?        00:00:00 /opt/datadog-agent/bin/trace-agent
dd-agent  2868  2862  0 00:26 ?        00:00:02 /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/ddagent.py
dd-agent  2869  2862  0 00:26 ?        00:00:01 /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/dogstatsd.py --use-local-forwarder
dd-agent  2872  2862  0 00:26 ?        00:00:02 /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/agent.py foreground --use-local-forwarder
root      3011     1  0 00:26 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      3014     1  0 00:26 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav
root      3016     1  0 00:26 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      3020     1  0 00:26 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      3022     1  0 00:26 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      3024     1  0 00:26 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      3026     1  0 00:26 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      3069  2386  0 00:27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  3071  3069  0 00:27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user  3072  3071  0 00:27 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root      3239     1  0 00:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3241  3239  0 00:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      3788  2386  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  3790  3788  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@notty
ec2-user  3791  3790  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
apache    4456  3239  0 00:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
ec2-user  4509  3072  0 00:48 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what happened.  Awhile ago I wiped away everything and installed new versions of php 7.0, mysql, and apache.  It seems yum update reinstalled php 5.6 on top of my php 7.0 version.